# Will definitely be Vs will be definitely

Tags: grammar, verbs, nouns, phrase-meaning, sentence-patterns

Why are we saying "There **will definitely be** some information", instead of "There **will be definitely** some information"?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are certain adverbs in English that are typically placed in mid position (as opposed to front or end position). Among these mid-position adverbs are *'certainty'* adverbs such as *definitely, probably, clearly, obviously*.

How mid-position adverbs are placed exactly depends on the verb construction they are modifying. In the case of a single verb form, the adverb precedes that form:

- She definitely said that.

However, if the verb is the copula *to be*, then the adverb typically comes after:

- She is definitely the best singer.

When the verb construction includes a modal, then the adverb comes between the modal and the lexical verb:

- She will definitely win the competition.

So the grammatical sentence in the present case is:

- There will definitely be some information.

Note, however, that the 'rules' above are not set in stone. Adverb positioning is pretty flexible. So you may see:

- There definitely will be some information.

Or

- There will be some information, definitely.

In both these cases, the untypical positioning serves to emphasise the word *definitely*.